# Django: creating M2M relationship inline

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to create a view with a formset of forms for the "Link" model. The problem is that in each form I would like the user to have the possibility of not just choosing from the already created TargetLink objects, but to edit them inline.

```
class ClientUrl(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(UpstreamClientModel, null=True)
    url = models.URLField(unique=True, null=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.url

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'url'
        ordering = ['url']

KEYWORD_TYPES = (
    ('PN', 'Pending'),
    ('MN', 'Money'),
    ('BR', 'Brand'),
    ('LT', 'Long Tail'),
)

class ClientKeyword(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(UpstreamClientModel, null=True)
    kw_type = models.CharField('keyword type', max_length=2, 
                choices=KEYWORD_TYPES, default='LT')
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=False)
    directions = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, 
            help_text='e.g: 25 chars, use "affordable rental cars"')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.keyword

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['keyword', ]
        unique_together = ('client', 'keyword')

class TargetLink(models.Model):
    keyword = models.ForeignKey(ClientKeyword, related_name='target_links')
    url = models.ForeignKey(ClientUrl, related_name='target_links')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{0}:{1}'.format(self.keyword, self.url)

class Link(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(UpstreamClientModel, related_name='links')
    target = models.ForeignKey(Target, related_name='links')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name='links')
    link_type = models.ForeignKey(LinkType, related_name='links')
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, blank=True, null=True, 
                related_name='links')
    site_url = models.URLField(blank=True, 
            help_text='leave blank until url is live')
    month = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    target_links = models.ManyToManyField(TargetLink, related_name='links')
```

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to have a form that is outside of your formset for the TargetLinks and use Knockout.js or another client-side framework to push the updated choices for TargetLinks to the target_links field in the formsets.

Comment: yeah, the problem is that both fields in TargetLink are also related to two other models, so how would I handle the creation of those objects?

Comment: Take a look at: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html That might give you an example of where I was going. Knockout (and other libraries) make it extremely easy to push state to the UI when the model changes, which would allow you to change the choices in your formset on the fly.